# Circle creates on previous coordinate on google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm creating marker and circle around 500 area. When user will be out of the boundary by drag the map another circle will create within same area of new generated marker. Issue is that its creating circle around previous generated marker instead of current generated marker.

You can check here:
http://jsbin.com/exiram/1

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Pay atention with the events in tme map. for every pan "drag the map" you make a new marker in center of the map and a new circle for that marker.

probaly, you have a listener that capture all mouse events and call the code to make markers and circles.

you can make 2 buttons in your page, one to make a marker and other to make a circle.

Comment: I want to generate circle around created marker when user drag the map. should together

Answer (score 0):

Im a little bit busy to post a full answer so please excuse my psudo code
Somthing like this will work !

```
var map;  // OUR MAP OBJECT
var circle; //OUR CIRCLE
var center;  // lat long holder
```

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() {        
  center = getCenter();   
  circle.setCenter(center);
});
```